# Camera constraints on Verold

Tags: verold

There is a problem that multiple users of my model have noticed, namely that when you right click the model ([here](http://www.verold.com/projects/54ceb6560f01ac093d379058)), the movements are hypersensitive. Orbit and zoom are fine and steady, but pan now more often than not results on the model rapidly shooting off into the distance. I've been playing with the camera controls to no avail and I don't want to simply remove the pan option for the client.

- Also, is there any way to transition between cameras without a fade, just a movement of the camera?
- Also, Verold not working on Internet Explorer 11... any news?

  Thanks

Comment: It happens very frequently when left clicking too, to the point that the model is non-navigable.

Comment: For instance, go to camera 3 and right or left click on the drum.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: problem was the focal point (white lined sphere). Had been set off accidentally far off into the distance (can be easily done without noticing and there is no undo). Just brought it back to the object.