# Gradual invisibility of an object

Tags: verold

Is there any way to make an object gradually disappear (without scripting), rather than go straight to invisibility using an event handler? I've tried importing an animated opacity change from 3ds Max, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently support animated material in FBX.

For now, I'd suggest triggering an EventHandler to modify the material properties. Here's how:

Add the Object Animator and Event Handler components to your object. In the Event Handler, choose whatever trigger you want (on pick, or whatever makes sense for your usecase). Then for the action, choose "Asset", select your material asset, then choose "Set Number", Opacity, then you can specify an opacity value and a transition time in seconds for the animation. I noticed on my machine that there is a bug during the transition, have recorded the bug and should get it fixed in the next few days. But that gets you what you need.

Ross

Comment: Perfects, that work, thanks. Can you take a look at this question here?; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417959/camera-constraints-on-verold